# How to select all int that contain searchstring

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code works correctly for string. How can I make it work for int?

```
var seat = from b in db.Seats
            select b;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{             
    seat = seat.Where(b => b.Seat.Contains(searchString));
}
```

Comment: What exactly becomes int? b.Seat or searchString or both?

Comment: Well, this is kind of unclear. What is the `int` exactly?

Comment: Are you saying you want to do a "substring" type check with ints?  So, 11 would match 110 and 511?

Comment: i've got some int values stored in my db. i'm using ajax to retrive data from database (search) on keyup event. i want  when i type 1 list 1,11 etc. curently work for string as it is written by juharr. thanks for the quick response

Comment: Is `b.Seat` an `int`?

Comment: Seat is a name of the field and int is a type.

Comment: I know that `int` is a type. Is `b.Seat` of type `int`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Convert integer value .ToString() so you can use the contains:

```
var seat = from b in db.SomeIntegerValue
            select b;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{             
    seat = seat.Where(b => b.SomeIntegerValue.ToString().Contains(searchString));
}
```

Comment: Seat is a name of the field and string is a type. I selected every seat from table an filtered them. It works ok in that example. Now, i want to do the same but type of the field is not enymore string than int. When i am typing 1 i want to get every values with 1,11,111....SearchString is a type of string but i will send numeric

Comment: if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                brojmjesta =  from e in db.BrojMjestas
                              where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)e.BrojSjedecihMjesta).Contains(searchString)
                              select e;
            } I found an answer on this cite. Thanks

Comment: The other way is simpler and does not require System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions

Comment: Did you get an error?  Can you post your changed code?

Comment: My post on 11th Dec solved problem.I realy don't know why            b => b.SomeIntegerValue.ToString().Contains(searchString) doesn't work.